# UIPopoverController How to fix for iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am getting an error / crash on iPad only when using the following code, iPhone works fine.

It is basically when trying to load the gallery to pick an image.

The debug error is;
"On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'"

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];
        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error accessing photo library"
                                  message:@"Device does not support a photo library"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Abort!"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
         }

    }
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {


        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];
        }
        else {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error accessing Camera"
                                  message:@"Device does not support a Camera"
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Abort!"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
        }

        }


    }


    -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
        NSLog(@"the info opf picker is %@",info);
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
        NSData *imageData;

        if ([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]) {
            UIImage *image2=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
            //UIImage *myscaledImage=[self scaleImage:image2 toSize:CGSizeMake(18, 24)];
            //imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myscaledImage);

            imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, .4);
            NSLog(@"the lenght of the edited image data is %d",[imageData length]);

        }
        else {
            UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

            //UIImage *myscaledImage=[self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(18, 24)];
            //imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myscaledImage);

            imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .6);
            NSLog(@"the lenght of the image dataa is %d",[imageData length]);

        }


        NSDictionary *tempDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageData,@"Image",@"Theme",@"Cell_Text",nil];
    //  NSLog(@"the custom array%@ and the row =%d", customArray,currentCameraRow);
        [customArray replaceObjectAtIndex:currentCameraRow withObject:tempDict];




        [pool drain];


        //NSLog(@"")
         [self startThread];        

        [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        [myCustomTableView reloadData];

        NSLog(@"size of myObject: %zd", malloc_size(myCustomTableView));

    }
```

Could anyone be so kind as to help with the code above ? I am guessing an if/else statement but have not the first idea of what it would be and where to place it.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

EDIT - Ok I now have it working the load from gallery now loads 'Photos' in a small window, where I can select, however there is no 'Select' or 'Choose' button, if I click the photo, there is no tick, to say it is selected, however it does select it, but to dismiss I click outside the window... So it works, but I am guessing I have missed something out, here is the code;

```
-(void) actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            if(popoverController != nil)
            {
                [popoverController release];
                popoverController = nil;
            }
            UIPopoverController* popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:picker];
            popoverController = popover;
            popoverController.delegate = self;
            [popover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 800)
                                     inView:self.view
                   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                   animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }



//      [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error accessing photo library"
                              message:@"Device does not support a photo library"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Abort!"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
     }

}
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {


    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType =UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
        [picker release];
    }
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Error accessing Camera"
                              message:@"Device does not support a Camera"
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Abort!"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

    }


}


-(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    NSLog(@"the info opf picker is %@",info);
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSData *imageData;

    if ([info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]) {
        UIImage *image2=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        //UIImage *myscaledImage=[self scaleImage:image2 toSize:CGSizeMake(18, 24)];
        //imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myscaledImage);

        imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, .4);
        NSLog(@"the lenght of the edited image data is %d",[imageData length]);

    }
    else {
        UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        //UIImage *myscaledImage=[self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(18, 24)];
        //imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myscaledImage);

        imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, .6);
        NSLog(@"the lenght of the image dataa is %d",[imageData length]);

    }


    NSDictionary *tempDict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:imageData,@"Image",@"Theme",@"Cell_Text",nil];
//  NSLog(@"the custom array%@ and the row =%d", customArray,currentCameraRow);
    [customArray replaceObjectAtIndex:currentCameraRow withObject:tempDict];




    [pool drain];


    //NSLog(@"")
     [self startThread];        

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [myCustomTableView reloadData];

    NSLog(@"size of myObject: %zd", malloc_size(myCustomTableView));



}

-(UIImage *)scaleImage:(UIImage *)image toSize:(CGSize)newSize {  
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);  
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];  
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;  
}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is very clear:

> On iPad, UIImagePickerController must be presented via UIPopoverController'

You need to put the image picker in a popover controller when run on the iPad. This is true when the `sourceType` is for the photo library. The camera based image picker can be shown as a full screen modal view controller.

This isn't an issue on the iPhone because the iPhone doesn't support the `UIPopoverController`.

The sample app `PrintPhoto` demonstrates how to show the image picker in a popover. Specifically, see `PrintPhotoViewController.m`.

Comment: Hi Maddy, I knew roughly that was the solution but my question is more how to do this as opposed to why it happened :) Could you assist with the code side at all?

Comment: OK I think I have fixed it to a point now... Please could you check my updated question as it is just a small bit of help I now need :)

Comment: @user1695971 Look at the sample app again. Look at the implementation of the image picker delegate method. You have to dismiss the popover on the iPad.

Comment: Hi Maddy, I still can't see it, I thought I was including everything correctly, whereabouts do you mean with the dismiss?

Comment: Did you look at the implementation of the image picker delegate in the sample app? Look how they dismiss the popover if it's set, otherwise they dismiss the modal view controller.

Comment: Still struggling, could you help with code example if possible, as I can't really see where I am going wrong here :(

Comment: Got it...!
if(popoverController){
        [popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
         popoverController = nil;
    }else

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    //present as a pop over vc
} else {
    //present as a modal vc
}
```

To present a popover you might use this method

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

You can read the documentation at this link [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: OK I think I have fixed it to a point now... Please could you check my updated question as it is just a small bit of help I now need :)